# Want to show all values of specific Item type in a div when button clicked with c#, jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, asp.net

I am creating a location management system using C#, SQL, and ASP.NET. I want to show the card div if my Item type equals "Artificial" in my database and do so with all my item types.

I also want to be able to update their specific counts. I'm currently only updating the general count instead of each count individually. Any suggestions?

Here's my code is below.

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.allItems)
            {

                @if (item.ItemType == "Artificial")
                {
            <div class="card-body" style="margin: 20px; padding: 50px; color: white; width: 700px; height: 700px; background-color: black;">

                <div class="hero-text">
                    <h1 style="font-size:50px">@item.Name</h1>
                </div>
                <h1>Category:</h1>
                <h2 class="card-title">@item.ItemType</h2>
                <h1>Item Type:</h1>
                <h2 class="card-title">@item.GroupType</h2>
                <h6 class="card-title">@item.Description</h6>
                <h1>Amount:</h1>
                <p class="card-text">@item.count</p>
                <div class="col">

                    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="update">
                        <input class="form-control" name="count" value="@item.HomebaseCount" type="number" min="0" step="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@item.Name" />
                        <h1>Homebase Count:</h1>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
                    </form>

                </div>

                <div class="col">

                    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="update">
                        <input class="form-control" name="count" value="@item.BunkerCount" type="number" min="0" step="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@item.Name" />
                        <h1>Bunker Count:</h1>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
                    </form>
                </div>



                <div class="col">

                    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="update">
                        <input class="form-control" name="count" value="@item.PouchCount" type="number" min="0" step="1" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@item.Name" />
                        <h1>Pouch Count:</h1>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update</button>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
                        }


                        }



                    </div>
                    
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Best Practices is that you should and have to move all your logic inside your Code Behind. Try not to use if statements or any hardcoded logic inside the `.cshtml` file.

Loosely coupling and the Single Responsibility principle is fundamental in the long run, and it's better to change your mindset and use these remarkable principles.

For example, if I were you, I would change the code as per below:

In code-behind:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IPersistence<FooEntity> _persistence;
    public IEnumerable<FooEntity>? Artificials { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(IPersistence<FooEntity> persistence)
    {
        _persistence = persistence;
    }
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        Artificials = _persistence.GetArtificials();

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Then I try to use my razor page just for binding the data (single responsibility principle).

```
@page
@model OdeToFood.UI.Pages.Restaurants.IndexModel
@{
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Artificials!)
{
    // TODO
    // 
    // 
}
```

Now you have a decoupled code, and if in the future you want to change the "Artificial" to "Superman" for example. Then you don't need to change every code and run all the tests and stuff. You just change the logic behind your interface.